# Casting String as DateTime in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with a following format.

```
PID     ID       Label        Value
------------------------------------------
1       1        First Name    Jenna
1       2        DOB           10/12/1980
```

I need to retrieve all PIDs where First name starting with J and Month of DOB is 10.

in my code, I retrieve these in DataTable in C# and then tried to use LINQ to retrieve the results I want. This is just an example. These Labels could be anything user defines.

using LINQ I am able to retrieve all PIDs where First Name start with J, but every time I tried to Cast Value for DOB I get cast not valid error. I cannot change the column type in the database since Value could contain any type of information.

Here's a piece of my code.  I am new to LINQ, and still trying to figure out around it.

```
var resultQuery = from r in query.AsEnumerable()
where (r.Field<string>("Label") == Label  &&
r.Field<DateTime>("Value").Month == 10)
select r.Field<int>("PID");
```

Comment: What's the DateTime value of "Jenna"?  I'm not sure that this is feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since not all items in the Value column of the table are convertible to `DateTime`, what you have will fail on invalid conversions. You can add in a clause that first checks that the value is a `DateTime` and only if it is, converts it and checks the `.Month` property.

```
DateTime d;
var resultQuery = from r in query.AsEnumerable()
                  where (r.Field<string>("Label") == Label &&
                      DateTime.TryParse(r.Field<string>("Value"), out d) && 
                      d.Month == 10)
                  select r.Field<int>("PID");
```

To potentially improve readability, you could also extract this out into a separate method:

```
var resultQuery = from r in query.AsEnumerable()
                  let d = TryGetDate(r.Field<string>("Value"))
                  where (r.Field<string>("Label") == Label &&
                      d != null && 
                      d.Month == 10)
                  select r.Field<int>("PID");

private DateTime? TryGetDate(string value)
{
    DateTime d;
    return DateTime.TryParse(value, out d) ? d : default(DateTime?);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of readability and "correctness", I believe it would be better to put the date logic in a separate method (DateTime? TryGetDate(string value)) and return null if not parse-able...

Comment: Thank you both.  If I just run the query the way goric suggested on it's own it doesn't error out, but if I am trying to convert resultquery to List and it fails. If I take out <DataTime>.Month == 10, my List works fine.     PID = resultQuery.ToList(); Where PID is defined at type of List<int>

Comment: Not only that, but your code, as is won't work.  Even if you can parse the string to a date, you can't just *cast* it to a date, which is what you are doing here.

Comment: @ioctlLR - That'll fail if it tries to parse that function on the server, though.

Comment: @Servy: Not sure I follow, `TryParse` would return true and initialize `d`, making it ready for use, or would return false and abort the `&&` logic.. What am I missing?

Comment: @goric At the time I posted that comment you weren't using `d`, you were using `r.Field<DateTime>("Value")` which will throw an exception every time.

Comment: @goric: That worked. Yes, I did use r.Field<DateTime> and didn't realized you edited you comment. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thanks everyone for investing your time to read my question and help.

Comment: @Bobson: It won't fail; LINQ will just revert to client-side processing (I'm assuming a SqlClient provider here).

Comment: @ioctlLR - Fair enough.  I assumed Linq-to-SQL, which can't handle function calls that way.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to end up filtering in memory which isn't very efficient.

So first select your data

```
var data= from r in query.AsEnumerable();
```

Then filter on the data

```
var filtered = from item in data
               where item.Label == "Label"
               && Convert.ToDateTime(item.DOB).Month == 10
               select item.PID;
```